# Formation of ester during preparation of Fluorescein

Tags: organic-chemistry, esters

I was going through PYQ of JEE where, I encountered the following question:

Q) Phthalic acid reacts with resorcinol in the presence of concentrated $H_2SO_4 $ to give :
In the solution provided I realised that conc. $H_2SO_4$ was acting as a dehydrating agent and leads to the formation of Fluorescein.

[image]

I have learnt that in presence of an acid catalyst esterification reaction is feasible, then what are the factors that prevent it from happening here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Phenolls are not alcohols.

Comment: @user55119 Thanks for the comment , I get it now that it is not possible for phenols to attack the carboxylic acids like alcohols as their nucleophilicity is lesse.

Comment: Certainly the para-acylation is faster.